# How do I remove duplicate values in a cell seperated with a /?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet, vba

I have multiple cells in excel that have as follows:

```
    b1= E4I8/E4I8/E4I8/E4I8
    b2=D3B2/B30C1/D3B2/D3B2/D3B2/B30C1


    multiple /xxxx/
```

How do I remove these duplicate text strings in the same cell?

Thank you

Comment: Is it important that the items remain in the same order?

Comment: are you willing to use VBA for the solution?

Answer (score 3):

This function uses the keys of a dictionary to build a unique list of parts from a passed-in string (add a reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`):

```
Public Function UniqueParts(separator As String, toParse As String) As String
    Dim d As New Scripting.Dictionary, part As Variant, i As Integer
    For Each part In Split(toParse, separator)
        d(part) = 1
    Next
    UniqueParts = Join(d.Keys, "/")
End Function
```

You can use this function in an Excel formula:

```
=UniqueParts("/","E4I8/E4I8/E4I8/E4I8")
```

or with a cell reference:

```
=UniqueParts("/",B2)
```

You can also use this inside a macro that iterates over a range of cells.

Comment: Good attempt, but `parts` isn't declared, isn't really used, and isn't needed.  Delete it and this will be a +1.

Comment: @chrisneilsen I was initially returning an array.

Answer (score 1):

If using VBA is allowed to solve you problem I propose the following function: (no references required!)

```
Function UniqueFromCell(rngCell, splitString)

Dim myCol As New Collection
Dim itmCol
Dim i As Long

Dim arrTMP As Variant
arrTMP = Split(rngCell, splitString)

For i = 1 To UBound(arrTMP)
    On Error Resume Next
    myCol.Add arrTMP(i), CStr(arrTMP(i))
    On Error GoTo 0
Next i

Dim result
For Each itmCol In myCol
    result = result & itmCol & splitString
Next

UniqueFromCell = Left(result, Len(result) - Len(splitString))

End Function
```

To call it in Excel you need to put two parameters: cell and separation mark:

```
=UniqueFromCell(B4,"/")
```

Comment: Thanks, in my national Excel we have `;` where you have `,`... but I changed into international standards :)