# Remove consecutive duplicates from text in cell

Tags: excel, user-defined-functions, vba

I almost found what I was wanting:

[How do I remove duplicate values in a cell seperated with a /?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15805157/how-do-i-remove-duplicate-values-in-a-cell-separated-with-a/26490117#26490117)

...but following on from this I wonder if it can be modified to remove only consecutive duplicates, rather than all duplicates. (I am referring to the answer by Kev spitz).

E.G, 1-1-3-4-2-2-2-2-5-2-1 would currently return 1/3/4/2/5

but I'd want it to return 1-3-4-2-5-2-1

I have looked at modifying the user defined function but to be honest it's too much for my limited ability :)

Appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
Public Function LJays(sIn As String) As String
    ary = Split(sIn, "-")
    LJays = ary(0)
    For i = LBound(ary) + 1 To UBound(ary)
        If ary(i) <> ary(i - 1) Then
            LJays = LJays & "-" & ary(i)
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: That kinda works, but it ignores a consecutive duplicate at the beginning and end of the string. It seems to be because the string doesn't begin and end in a " - ". I can get round this by adding an extra " - " at the beginning and end of the previous stage of what I'm doing.  Unless there's an easy edit to do that as part of the funtion, then remove the extras at the end of the function?

Comment: @LJays99 Let me run some tests.

Comment: I've updated the "-"'s to " - " because the format I am using includes the spaces..........Then I added this line to the beginning: sIn = " - " & sIn & " - "                       That's got rid of all the consecutive duplicates, but i'm still stuck with an extra - at the beginning and end.  Can probably google this now but if you know off the top of your head.  Cheers!

Comment: I can help you as soon as I can get to a real computer!

Comment: In the cell data, is there a **space** before and after each **dash??**

Comment: Yes there is which I don't think I stated correctly to start with so sorry about that.  Thanks for all your help. I've now sorted it with a couple of lines at the end to remove the extra dashes..........

Comment: Public Function LJays(sIn As String) As String
    sIn = " - " & sIn & " - "
    ary = Split(sIn, " - ")
    LJays = ary(0)
    For i = LBound(ary) + 1 To UBound(ary)
        If ary(i) <> ary(i - 1) Then
            LJays = LJays & " - " & ary(i)
        End If
    Next i
    LJays = Right(LJays, Len(LJays) - 3)
    LJays = Left(LJays, Len(LJays) - 3)
End Function